# Cannot export extra data from Freebase using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, freebase

A newbie question,

I am trying to use [Freebase Suggest](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest) as a tagging resource for my Django project. I want to extract item name, type and id. For example, as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV4tg.jpg), I want to extract the name 'Pearl Jam' ,its id '/en/pearl_jam', and the type 'band'.

How can I post this data to my view?

Using the function below I can only create links to the tags.

```
$(function(){
   $("#myinput").suggest().bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
     $('#myinput').val(''); // clear the input
     $('#returnValueOfFreebase').append('<a href="http://freebase.com/view'+ data.id +'">'+      data.name +'</a>  ')})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the name and the ID from `data.name` and `data.id`. You can also access the [notable type](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Notable_types) from your callback function by using `data['n:type'].name` like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#myinput").suggest().bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
     $('#myinput').val(''); // clear the input
     $('#returnValueOfFreebase').append('<a href="http://freebase.com/view'+ data.id +'">'+ data.name +'</a> (' + data['n:type'].name + ')')})
});
```

If you want to capture this data and post it back to your web app, you can create some hidden inputs and set their value from the Freebase suggest callback. Like this:

```
<input id="notable_type" name="notable_type" type="hidden" />

$("#myinput").suggest().bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
    $("#notable_type").val(data['n:type'].id);
});
```

Comment: Shawn's answer will get you what you asked for, but note that the use of IDs has been deprecated by Google, so you should probably use the MID (/m/0d193h) instead.  In both cases, the leading slash (/) is part of the ID.  You may also want to store the mid/id of the notable type as well as the name, since that's the canonical way of referencing it.

Comment: @TomMorris but some object has more than 1 MIDs like java programming language. "/m/07sbkfb" which is equal to ID and "/m/04j38sw" . Why is that so?

Comment: When two topics are merged, the "winning" topic inherits all the keys/IDs of the other topic, except for the GUID, which is a unique synthetic ID.  This allows apps which stored either of the original keys to continue to work even if their instance of the "Java programming language" topic was the losing one.

Answer (score 1):

New Api use data['notable'] instead of data['n:type']